# error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I'm having some problems compiling my code. It says,

> error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member
>   functions or non-static data member initializers

part of the code where the error shows up

```
    double getR() {
    return this->r;
}
double getG() {
    return this->g;
}
double getB2() {
    return this->b2;
}
```

also here

```
    rez.r = this->r / 2 + a.getR() / 2;
    rez.g = this->g / 2 + a.getG() / 2;
    rez.b2 = this->b2 / 2 + a.getB2() / 2;
```

Any ideas?

THAT WAS FIXED.

Same error on this part of code now...

```
    rez.r = this->r / 2 + a.getR() / 2;
    rez.g = this->g / 2 + a.getG() / 2;
    rez.b2 = this->b2 / 2 + a.getB2() / 2;
```

it also says

> error C2227: left of '->r' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Answer (score 15):

You need to add the class scope to your methods, for example if your class is named `YourClass` then your function would be

```
double YourClass::getR() {
    return this->r;
}
```

Otherwise `getR` is a free function, and therefore has no `this` to operate on. The same goes for your other methods.

Comment: okay that seems to be fixed, thanks. but what about this code? 

where do i add te class scope on this one?

 edit : i editted the main post

Comment: The same idea applies. Is that code snippet within a class method? If not, it cannot use `this`. I cannot tell just by seeing those few lines and not the function they are used within.

Comment: If I'd post whole function, would that help? As I cannot understand what to do :(