# error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt creator 5.10 in widows 7.

I have writen a tcp socket program.

```
#include <QTcpSocket>
QTcpSocket *tcpClient;
tcpClient = new QTcpSocket(this);
```

Error:

```
1   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2   'tcpClient' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'QTcpSocket *'
3    'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267535/error-c2355-this-can-only-be-referenced-inside-non-static-member-functions

Comment: Which C++ book are you using to learn C++?

Answer (score 0):

If `tcpClient` is a global variable, as this code suggests, you can't initialize it in a separate statement that is also in global scope. Only variable declarations, namespace declarations, and functions can be in global scope.

Also, `this` can only be used inside of the implemention body of a non-static class method.